# Check whether text file of values follows convention using regex

Tags: python, regex, file, parsing, text

Good day all!

I'm writing a python script to parse text files containing exactly 2 columns of integers, space or tab separated, something like this example:

```
3141 5926
535 89
79 32

11 2
1 4
```

I want to be able to reject a file from the get go if it doesn't follow this convention (eg 1 or 3 values or more in one line, letters...)

So far I came up with
`^\d+[ \t]+\d+$`
which is arguably not much (I tried different approaches to no avail, I'm not super familiar with regex unfortunately). I was thinking of writing an expression that will either return a match or none in case the file doesn't follow convention.

My questions are:

1. Is regex even the right tool or are conventional methods of reading the file and manipulating strings better?
2. Where do I go from here? Is my approach of all-or-nothing even worth it?
3. Is there a way to not only match the whole text file but also be able to extract the last paragraph?

I'm working on python3 using `re`.

Any pointers are appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do what I initially set out to do.

I used the following pattern:

`\n*(?:(?:[ \t]*\d+[ \t]+\d+[ \t]*\n)*(?:[ \t]*\d+[ \t]+\d+[ \t]*)\n\n)*(?P<last>(?:[ \t]*\d+[ \t]+\d+[ \t]*\n)*(?:[ \t]*\d+[ \t]+\d+[ \t\n]*))`

which matches a text containing pairs of integers (one pair per line) separated by either spaces or tabs. The pattern also allows for a single white-line between groups of pairs (like in my example). It also captures the last bunch of pairs in a group named `last`.

Now, this will match with a partially-compliant file, which I don't want. The trick was to use `re.fullmatch()` instead of `re.match()`. This method returns `None` if there's only a partial match.

The pattern above does the following:

- `\n*` matches with leading line-breaks.
- `(?:(?:[ \t]*\d+[ \t]+\d+[ \t]*\n)*(?:[ \t]*\d+[ \t]+\d+[ \t]*)\n\n)*` matches with all except the last bunch of pairs (hence the `*` at the end):

  - `(?:[ \t]*\d+[ \t]+\d+[ \t]*\n)*` matches between 0 and unlimited times with single-line pairs or integers, allowing leading and trailing spaces/tabs
  - `(?:[ \t]*\d+[ \t]+\d+[ \t]*)\n\n` matches exactly once with the last line of a bunch of pairs. This, effectively serves as a base-case for the repeating pattern above.
- `(?P<last>(?:[ \t]*\d+[ \t]+\d+[ \t]*\n)*(?:[ \t]*\d+[ \t]+\d+[ \t]*))` follows the same rationale discussed above where it serves as a base-case to the last repeating non-capturing group. It allows for an unlimited amount of trailing while-lines
- `\n*` matches with trailing line-breaks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `pandas` to load the text files into a dataframe with [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) and then check whether all values are integers and whether the number of columns in 2 or not:

```
import pandas as pd
from glob import glob

files = glob('/path/to/files/*.txt') #get a list of all txt files

for i in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(i, sep=' |\t', engine='python', header=None) #sep=' |\t' will process both space- and tab-delimited files
    if (df.dtypes == 'int64').all() and len(df.columns) == 2: #check if all values are integers and if the number of columns is 2
        #do something here
```

How to read only the last paragraph depends on how the files are structured, if the second paragraph is always the 4th row you could access it with `df[3:]`. If there is no pattern you could extract the second paragraph like this:

```
with open('filename.txt') as file:
    data = [[int(x) for x in i.strip().split()] for i in file.readlines()] #create list of lists of items in rows
    data = data[data.index([])+1:] #slice list after the empty row
```